# PHP PDO transaction rollBack doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, rollback

How is everything
Please can anyone help me in this
I'm trying to use PHP PDO transaction and there is a problem that I face and I can't deal with it.
rollBack function doesn't work when It catch an exception
Here is the connection code

```
$host   = 'localhost';
$user   = 'root';
$pass   = '';
$error  = '';
$dbname = 'tameras_finance';
// Set DSN
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . '; dbname=' . $dbname;
// Set options
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);
// Create a new PDO instanace
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $dbh->exec("set names utf8");
}
//Catch any errors
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

and here the code

```
try{
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $dbh->query('SET @newDebit = (SELECT max(`debtor_id`) + 1 AS maxDebit FROM `vocher`)');
    for($x = 0; $x < count($debits); $x++){
        $dbh->query('UPDATE `vocher` SET `debtor_id` = @newDebit, `status_id` = "4" WHERE `id` = '.$debits[$x]);
    }

    for($x = 0; $x < count($others); $x++){
        $columns = '`acc_id`, `value`, `date`, `desc`, `reject`, `vo_type_id`, `user`, `debtor_id`';
        $vals  = "'".$accs[$x]."','".$values[$x]."','".$dates[$x]."','".$descs[$x]."','1','1','".$user."', @newDebit";
        if($others[$x] == 'e'){
            $columns .= ', `cheque_no`, `available_date`, `issue_date`, `bank_id`';
            $vals  .= ", '".$sns[$x]."', '".$availdates[$x]."', '".$issueDates[$x]."', '".$banks[$x]."'";
        }
        $dbh->query("INSERT INTO creditor (".$columns.") VALUES (".$vals.")");
        if($lists[$x] != 'e'){
            $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
            $q  = 'INSERT INTO `creditor_cc` (`creditor`, `cc`) VALUES ';
            for($y = 0; $y < count($lists[$x]); $y++){
                $dif = count($lists[$x]) - $y;
                $q .= '(';
                $q .= '"' . $lastId . '",';
                $q .= '"'.$lists[$x][$y].'"';
                $q .= ')';
                if($dif > 1){
                    $q .= ',';
                }
            }
            $dbh->query($q);
        }
    }
    $dbh->commit();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $error = $e->getMessage();
    $dbh->rollBack();
}
```

This code doesn't rollback
Please note that:

- $sns, $others, $accs, $values, $dates, $descs, $availdates,
  $issueDates and $banks are arrays with the same size
- Also $lists is a two dimension array with the same size

please help me with this why this code doesn't rollBack

Comment: It rolls back the database transaction, it doesn't have anything to do with PHP strictly. I.e. it's not going to change your variable values.

Comment: Just a guess: try starting the transaction outside of the try catch block...

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work @Jochen Schultz  if I have four rows to insert and I have some exception at third insert it insert the first two rows and stop but I guess it suppose to rollback the first two rows

Answer (score 5):

Transactions are not supported on MySQL's default table type `MyISAM`. You need to make sure you're using `InnoDB` tables.

Also check to make sure the exception that's being thrown is `PDOException` or it'll fall through the `try/catch` and not hit your rollback.

Comment: I'm using InnoDB  tables

Comment: Bummer :-s What's the exception that's being thrown look like? Just make sure it's firing as a `PDOException` and not something else and being caught in some outer try catch.

Comment: Instead of `$e->getMessage();` call `var_dump($e);` and check the class name of the exception object.

Comment: I tried to call var_dump($e) but as you said @Kevin Nagurski but it didn't catch any exception I don't know why

Comment: It looks like it's not a `PDOException` that's being thrown. Change `catch (PDOException $e) {` to `catch (Exception $e) {` and put the `var_dump` in place. Because the `catch` statement is very specific, if it's not `PDOException`, it'll drop through to the next catch.

Comment: It didn't catch the exception also :(

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the full code here as it is too long

Comment: `$dbh->beginTransaction();
try{
  //same code
  
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  //echo $error = $e->getMessage();
  var_dump($e);
  $dbh->rollBack();
 }

$dbh->commit();`

Comment: By not having a `throw $e;` in the `catch` and having `$dbh->commit();` AFTER the `catch`, in the event of an exception, it will call `rollBack()` immediately followed by `commit()`. There probably won't be any effect from that, but it's something to bear in mind. Throw a `die();` after the `var_dump` to get it to stop in the meantime. If that doesn't shed some light, then it isn't getting into the `try/catch` and you probably have an error somewhere else in the script.

Comment: $dbh->commit() was in try{} at the original code , and I tried to get it back  and add throw $e and it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

I would say it shoud be done this way:

```
$pdo = new \PDO(/*...*/);

$pdo->beginTransaction();

try {
//...
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}

$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: didn't catch any exception and doesn't rollBack too